# ASP.NET CSS file not loaded when adding HttpModule to web.config

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5

i am making a Website with c# and ASP.NET 3.5, i just made an HttpModule to handle the NHibernate Session Life (Open and close).
I added it to the web.config and everything works fine. (all the query, code, etc working fine) except that CSS file of my masterpage is not loading !!

it's so strange for me,
Do you have any idea what is the cause of this behavior ?

Thank You all,

Comment: can you post the code where the css is loaded? is it dynamically or you just define it in head section?

Comment: it is defined in the head with the link href="style.css" tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at last i found the solution, the problem source is working with the session in the HttpModule events cause strange problems.

> It looks like it is a known issue and whether or not session state is available is actually decided... by the SessionStateModule itself!
>   Briefly, in order to force session state to load current Context.Handler, usually DefaultHttpHandler, has to be replaced in the PostMapRequestHandler event by some other handler, implementing IRequiresSessionState. To be safe, my dummy handler carries a reference to the original handler, and I swap it back in the PostAcquireRequestState event, once the dummy handler fulfilled its purpose.

actually it is a known issue in Asp.net and IIS and the solution is reported [Here at ASP.NET forum](http://forums.asp.net/p/1098574/1665773.aspx). also there is  a sample code to solve the problem in link. 
I tested and my problem solved!

Thanks All,