# Not able to access session in Httpmodule for static resources like css /js/ image files

Tags: asp.net, image, session, unmanaged, httpmodule

I have created a HTTPModule. Session information is retrieved using PreRequestHandlerExecute. It is working well for aspx pages. But while loading css/js or any image files, Session is null.

I have gone through the link [ASP.NET CSS file not loaded when adding HttpModule to web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278339/asp-net-css-file-not-loaded-when-adding-httpmodule-to-web-config)

But could not get the implementation.

Anyone has any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find that your static files are being handled by the [StaticFileHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404287%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and as such wouldn't fire off session events as the session won't be being activated for efficiency purposes.

You could configure IIS to pass static files through a different handler (the PageHandler for example) but really you'd need to know if that was required first. You haven't described why you want sessions to be available for static files.