# Website CSS loading issue with IE and Edge

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

I have a website running perfectly fine on Chrome, Firefox, Safari etc. however, the CSS does not load in Internet explorer (any version) as well as in MS Edge browser.

The Console shows this infamous error related to MIME Type:

```
SEC7113: CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch
File: application-2015-2a0565839ee60a029c49fc918e3625e9.css
SEC7113: CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch
File: CustomCss.css
SEC7113: CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch
File: print.css
```

I have checked in the code, and this is how it is in the `<head>`

```
// ASP.NET MVC code - .cshtml layout file
<link href='@Url.Content("/Content/application-2015-2a0565839ee60a029c49fc918e3625e9.css")' media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href='@Url.Content("/Content/CustomCss.css")' media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href='@Url.Content("/Content/2015/print.css")' media="print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

I have checked in the IE Developer Tools, and the css indeed returned with incorrect MIME type (coming as blank) in IE instead of stylesheet or text/css as in Chrome or Firefox:

**IE:**
[image]

**Chrome:**
[image]

I have checked in IIS, the mime type for .css is mapped as expected:
[image]

How can I make IE to understand the Mime type and let it load it correctly.

Any help is highly appreciated.

**EDIT**

As suggested, also checked the Registry value for .css in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT and this seems ok as below:
[image]

Also, ensured that no program is associated with CSS to open.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16473610/internet-explorer-css-was-ignored-due-to-mime-type-mismatch-on-local-files-no

Comment: thanks; I have seen that and tried all the options mentioned there - also ensured that css is not defaulted to open with a particular program.

Also, getting the same behaviour on server as well as on my local machine

Comment: Does the problem persist if you use those files in a simple HTML page?

Comment: I tried with the simple HTML page, but you guess it right, with simple HTML, the issue is not there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27490193/css-is-not-loaded-at-all-in-internet-explorer-sec7113

Comment: @LaljiTadhani: How does above question helps as I already said the CSS are not served with proper Mime Type and I have tried all I know and can search for to deliver the css with correct Mime Type

Comment: When you are looking at the MIME types page, is this the MIME types for your whole server or just your website? If it's for your whole server, does your website inherit it's mappings from the server level node?

Comment: I would also recommend opening up a packet sniffer like Fiddler. It will show you the non-parsed version of what is in the HEAD of the HTTP Response. This is important as it would actually show if the content type is being passed down correctly.

Comment: Thanks @k2snowman69, as I already mentioned, the content type is not passed down correctly and sent as text/plain instead of text/css

Comment: The server has only one website

Comment: Even though the server has only one website, the root node (which contains application pools and your sites) has it's set of MIME types and your website (under the sites folder) has it's own set of MIME types which can be overridden through the web.config file. Your picture seems to show the root node and I just wanted you to check the website specific settings.

Comment: double checked - the mime type is setup all across for the root as well as for the website
This is also happening for running through localhost

Comment: @PankajGaur is this live somewhere we can troubleshoot?

Comment: Did you tried to put it on some other server? Or it is on your machine (localhost)?
And are you sure it not a problem of the css file content? I know it would be wierd but I seen wierd stuff before on IE:D. Double check it just delet all css and try if it will be the same with for e.g background red.

Comment: Did u check this link https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cjacks/2010/12/28/debugging-a-css-issue-with-ie9-mtley-cre-edition/. The content type value has to follow the exact specifications. Can you share a fiddler trace of response?

Comment: What is the version of windows and IIS you are using to host your application?

Answer (score 1):

This is because under default settings, “static content” is not installed with IIS.

To enable this on a Windows Server 2008 machine do the following

1. Fire up Server Manager
2. Select Web Server under Roles – notice that Static Content is not installed

[image]

Select Add Role Services from the right hand menu

[image]

Check Static content and install

i think it works for you

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that there was an HTTP Module which was the root cause of it as it turns out to be a known issue with ASP.NET, IIS and HTTP Module aas mentioned here:
[ASP.NET CSS file not loaded when adding HttpModule to web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278339/asp-net-css-file-not-loaded-when-adding-httpmodule-to-web-config)

Following this and handling in Http Module explicitly for css, fixed this issue.

Thanks for everyone for taking time out and providing your expert comments

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've tried everything that seems to have worked for others.

Try setting the output to the mime type through the ASP.NET framework:

```
Response.ContentType = "text/css";
```

Have you tested using a load function?

```
Response.ContentType = "text/css"
Response.AddHeader("Header")
Response.WriteFile("CSS File.css")
Response.End()
Response.Clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

### You should check these things because if IE

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

or

```
type="text/css" instead of type="css/stylesheet" when importing the stylesheet.
```

Comment: I am using text/css